# Condensation on Skylight

Tags: insulation, windows, condensation, winterizing, skylight

So this is my first winter in my new house and I noticed the skylight on the second floor has a lot of condensation on the inside now that the weather is getting colder. It's an old single pane and looks and probably is plastic not glass. It for sure needs to be replaced but I was hoping to wait it out until the spring. The good news is that it doesn't leak when it rains. Its sealed very well and I actually got on the roof recently and added more roof seal for the winter.

The problem is there is a lot of steam buildup on the glass and it drips onto the floor. Any ideas on a temporary fix for a few months? It had a clear film on the frame when I moved in that I took off and I just realized it was probably shrink wrap for this exact reason. I'm going to put it back on and see if it helps. There is plenty of room between the ceiling and the actual glass so do you guys think it would be a good idea put two or three layers of shrink wrap or bubble wrap? I'm not so much concerned with letting light in or letting heat out. I just want to stop the dripping.

Answer (score 2):

Just a layer of shrink wrap will be fine , as long as you prevent the moisture from getting up to it it will quit sweating.

Make sure to run the exhaust fans in the bathroom when bathing or using hot water to shave, also run your exhaust when cooking.

I found some really good stuff for sealing windows in the past that you put on the frame and shrink it with a hair dryer, I hade to make a “picture frame” and mount it as I had no trim mine was all Sheetrock. I made a frame put the film on it and then used finishing nails to hold it in place you can barely see the film , I thought I might take it down in the summer but it has been place for almost 5 years now 
The stuff I used was 3m for insulation but I don’t remember a name.

Comment: I would use an actual window insulation kit. They're inexpensive, much tougher than plastic food wrap, easier to work with, and are virtually invisible when done right. You can just leave it up year-round.

Comment: All the home stores up north should have "Indoor Window Insulation" kits this time of season.  Clear shrink plastic sheets and double sided tape.  You can mount them directly to the trim, or build a frame yourself.   I made one for my kitchen alcove.  And they also come in sliding door sizes.
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Frost-King-E-O-Indoor-Window-Insulation-Kit-3-per-Pack-V73-3H/100135637

Comment: @davem that shrink film is similar to what I used it really worked well, I thought it might get dusty as we have a riding arena just behind our house but it sealed up so well no dust gets in. +